# Show only fail reasons when running rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd

When running a test on the command line which fails usually it shows something like this example:

```
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
F

Failures:

  1) Creating Post A user creates a new post
     Failure/Error: visit '/'

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/"
     # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
     # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
     # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
     # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
....
```

Is it possible to show **only** the fail error, by a config setting or something? so the test would show only this

```
F

Failures:

  1) Creating Post A user creates a new post
     Failure/Error: visit '/'

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/"
```

without all that paths showing at the bottom. I think sometimes its easier to detect the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I don't think there's a way to get what you want. At first, I believed you could use [backtrace filtering](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/configuration/excluding-lines-from-the-backtrace), but evidently [when you filter everything, RSpec forces a full backtrace](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/754#issuecomment-11625446).

Sadly, the best I can offer is:

```
$ rspec spec/models/customer_spec.rb | grep -Ev '^\s+# '
```

But you lose all color in your output. =\

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll mark your answer as correct since I haven't got any more replies. However I'd appreciate if someone else (or even you) knows a better option